HighChart (area) change series color dynamically inTypeScript
How to change HighChart (area3D) series color in react TypeScript? series data will be chage with setData() but i get this error " TS2304: Cannot find name 'SeriesOptionsType'. " while trying to change series color using chart.series[i].update(SeriesOptionsType,true).
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly<ComponentProps<AreaChartProps>>, prevState: Readonly<any>, snapshot?: any) {
        if (this.chartRef.current){
            const chart = this.chartRef.current.chart as Chart;
            for ( let i:number =0 ; i < chart.series.length ; i++){
                chart.series[i].setData(this.props.props.series[i].data,true,true,true);

                chart.series[i].color = this.props.props.series[i].color
                chart.series[i].update(SeriesOptionsType,true)
            }
        }else {
            console.log( "error chart reference not available")
        }
    }


and also get this error "TS2339: Property 'color' does not exist on type 'SeriesOptionsType'.   Property 'color' does not exist on type 'SeriesTiledwebmapOptions'."   when using below code
chart.series[0].options.color = "#008800";
chart.series[0].update(chart.series[0].options);


I searched all the net, but i didn't find anything about changing the color using typescript. Also i'm new to scripting languages

To update the chart color you should use update method and over there specify a new color for the series. If you're having errors from TypeScript I suggest writing an interface that will extend the SeriesOptionsType.
Something like in this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-property-xxx-doesnt-exist?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Thanks for your reply I managed to do it with another method.

Sure thing, congrats on solving the issue!
